# Angular JS - Check when a user has entered something into a field

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way in angular to check when a user has typed something into a field.

So when they start typing I can do something like:

```
console.log('the user has started');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field is bound to some variable in the scope (let say `foo`, you can do the following:

```
$scope.$watch('foo', function(value){
   console.log('the user has started', value);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-dirty` like this:

```
<form name="myform">
    <span ng-show="myform.myinput.$dirty"> the user has started </span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="mod" name="myinput" />
</form>
```

Take a look at [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform)